# How to get a collider that fits a sprite in 2D or 2.5D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite, polygon

I am trying to use a polygon collider 2D on a random shape that I cut out from a texture.
The texture is therefore 2D and I want a collider to automatically match the edges/borders of my cut shape.

I don't know if I am using the right collider type, but the only one I found that matched somehow the contour of my shape was Polygon Collider 2D. However, as seen in the image, the shape is taken into account but the interior is rotated according to a 2 dimensional space.

[image]

However, I am using this texture in VR and it can be anywhere around the player, not only in one flat direction.

Is there an equivalent of poylgon Collider 2D I could use for this purpose, or am I doing it wrong ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Something to take note of, if this is for pure 2d purposes then it will be fine to use 2d colliders, however when you mention 2.5d you will need to use 3d colliders.

Comment: The thing is I am using polygoncollider2D because I did not find an alternative for 3D. When the collider is in the camera frustum it should trigger a response. However it only works in the area the vertices are visible (in the middle on this image)

What else could I use to fulfill this requirement for the entire cut png visible on screen? (Collider, meshes perhaps?)

Comment: Still stuck with that... :/